# Installing Selenium on Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, pip

i am trying to install Selenium on my computer.

I downloaded Python and as far as i know PiP is already installed, but when i write in my command prompt "pip" , nothing happends, it just sits there and does nothing and i can't write in the console anymore, like its loading.

If i write Python in the console there comes up version and commands work as they should in the Python Client.

I do add the right paths and i double check alot of times.

Anyone had this problem? tried pretty much every solution out there.

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux, ...?

Comment: Windows 8 , tried so much..

Comment: If **pip -V** does not show the version, something is wrong with your installation. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows